# Why is the battery on my Panasonic dmc tz8 draining in a few hours even though it's off?

Tags: battery, panasonic-lumix, battery-drain

The battery of my Panasonic dmc tz8 is empty after a few hours or 1 day without using the camera. It is **off**. I tried several new batteries no success. Does someone know what the possible problem is?

Comment: Did this just start, or has it been happening all along?

Comment: It is already 1 year and I bought 4 new batteries, same problem occurs

Answer (score 1):

There is a short/leak somewhere in your camera's circuitry.  I had this problem with a digicam once: the power button itself was allowing enough current to leak through when off that it would get warm to the touch.  The expedient solution is to only put the battery in when you're shooting.